# NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name 'xyz.in-addr.arpa'

Tags: dns, jndi, javax

I'm trying to get a DNS Name from a DNS Server:

```
DirContext ctx = null;
Attributes attrs = ctx.getAttributes(Ip ,new String[] {"PTR"});
```

but it throws the exception:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '11.70.168.192.in-addr.arpa'

Answer (score 1):

According to the [opendns website](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227986827-FAQ-What-are-common-DNS-return-or-response-codes-), response code 3 error means that the `Domain name does not exist`.

This can be caused by 3 things:

1. Website is offline or having server issues
2. Website does not exist
3. Website has moved servers but DNS cache has not updated yet